# Matrix, Vector, Multiplication

Tags: matrix, vector, multiplication

I understand what Vector and matrix are.

1. But I don't know what is vector-matrix multiplication for? How the mathematician come up this theory?
2. What is matrix-matrix multiplication for? How come up this theory?

I know how to calculate them, but no idea what it looks like in a 3D space.

3. Can I understand that: Matrix Multiplication is: First we break one of two Matrixes to several vectors; Second, we do Vector-Matrix Multiplication and then adding all of them together?

Thank you for your explanation

Comment: I think [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRv3-LnEUjg) a good example

Answer (score 1):

### Basics

Matrices can map numbers in 2 dimensions. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRv3-LnEUjg) shows a good example of how to calculate with matrices.

Matrix A = items sold per day (5 x 3 dimension)

```
             c
             o
             o  c
             k  a  p
             i  k  i
             e  e  e
             s  s  s
             
monday     [ 3  5  3 ]
tuesday    [ 7  1  2 ]
wednesday  [ 2  5  3 ]
thursday   [ 5  4  0 ]
friday     [ 3  4  4 ]
```

Matrix B = Price per item (3 x 1 dimension)

```
              €
cookies    [  4 ]
cakes      [ 10 ]
pies       [  8 ]
```

In order to be able to multiply 2 matrices, the 2nd dimension of the 1st matrix **MUST** match the 1st dimension of the 2nd matrix `(5 x 3) * (3 x 1)` (3's must match), and this multiplication will result in a `5 x 1` matrix.

In this example we're multiplying a (days/item) matrix with a (items/price) matrix, and we're expecting a (days/price) matrix that indicates how much we earn per day.

You can immediately see why the numbers of columns of the first matrix must match the number of rows of the second matrix here.

### Multiplication

In order to multiply the matrices, we first position them in a better way:

```
                           €
                        [  4 ]
                        [ 10 ]
                        [  8 ]

monday     [ 3  5  3 ]  [    ]
tuesday    [ 7  1  2 ]  [    ]
wednesday  [ 2  5  3 ]  [    ]
thursday   [ 5  4  0 ]  [    ]
friday     [ 3  4  4 ]  [    ]
```

As demonstrated below, each element in the resulting matrix is the sum of following multiplications:

```
                            €
                      ---[  4 ]
                    ╱  --[ 10 ]
                  ╱  ╱  -[  8 ]
                ╱  ╱  ╱     |
              ╱  ╱  ╱       |
monday     [ 3  5  3 ]   [    ]
tuesday    [ 7  1  2 ]   [    ]
wednesday  [ 2  5  3 ] - [ 82 ]
thursday   [ 5  4  0 ]   [    ]
friday     [ 3  4  4 ]   [    ]
```

So for the third element, the result is as follows:

```
2 cookies * 4 €/cookie + 5 cakes * 10 €/cake + 3 pies * 8 €/pie = 82 €
```

### Extending the example

If you also want to know how much time you're spending to bake the stuff you're selling, you can add those numbers to the second matrix as well:

```
              €   min.
cookies    [  4     2  ]
cakes      [ 10    30  ]
pies       [  8    20  ]
```

Multiplying them:

```
                            €   min
                      ---[  4     2  ]
                    ╱  --[ 10    30  ]
                  ╱  ╱  -[  8    20  ]
                ╱  ╱  ╱     |     |
              ╱  ╱  ╱       |     |
monday     [ 3  5  3 ]   [           ]
tuesday    [ 7  1  2 ]   [           ]
wednesday  [ 2  5  3 ] - [ 82    214 ]
thursday   [ 5  4  0 ]   [           ]
friday     [ 3  4  4 ]   [           ]
```

Will give you

```
R(3,2) = 2 * 2 + 5 * 30 + 3 * 20 = 214
```

So as a result, you know your earnings per day, and your spent minutes per day for the items you sell